# Is it possible to use laser-like technology to create effective force field?

Tags: forces, electric-fields, field-theory

By laser-like lechnology I mean a coherent ray of particals or waves with the same amplitude/energy.
This ray would be emited on limited distance (lets say 2meters) where it will be absorbed by receiever. The energy from receiver is again used for emiter.
The idea is to create forcefield inside "window-like" frame where particals/waves are emited from left to right (or other direction).

Example:
In vacuum we will emit coherent ray of photons in infrared as laser from left side of the frame to the right side. With intensity milions of lumens. But since they will be dirrected only inside the frame they will be invisibe from outside (in vacuum).

If in this example we take a flashlight and use it to send ray of white light photons in 90° angle to the ray emited inside the frame...does the ray in the frame block any of the photons from the flashlight?
If so - can you please dirrect me to some more detailed information about it?

Comment: In what sense is that a forcefield? But no, the laser beams in the frame will have virtually no effect on the flashlight beam. Photons *can* interact with other photons, but the effect is tiny for low energy photons, you need to use very high energy gamma rays before anything significant happens.

Comment: Is the intensity of the ray insignificant compared to type of particals?

Comment: I mean even photons can have big impact if there is enough of them. With high energy particles I see obstacles with the emition and receving. Sure it would be cool if we can emit atoms of carbon in form of tubes at speed of light...Low energy paricals seemed more practical choice. Ou well...thanks for explanation

Comment: I really thought it is matter of intensity of the photon ray. Like how many bilion lumens you need to stop a bulet that impact the ray at 90°...sorry if I missunderstood

Comment: It comes down to probabilities. If the probability of a flashlight photon being deflected by a frame photon is small, you have a greater chance of that happening if there are a lot of frame photons, so intensity does have some effect. But the probability of an infrared photon causing an effect is so low that the required intensity needed to cause even a tiny deflection of a single flashlight photon is ridiculous. But if both the flashlight & the frame are using gamma photons with energy in the neighbourhood of the rest energy of the electron, then deflection is much more likely.

Comment: I see. Well I did not consider that. Thanks....So if it would be a ray of electrons the effect is much more significant. Correct?

Comment: Or ray of pozitrons perhaps?

Comment: A beam of matter particles (or antimatter particles) has rather different properties to a beam of photons. Just ask [Anatoli Bugorski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoli_Bugorski). ;)

Comment: Ou yea I remember that from CrashCourse Psychology. Well if it was not his head but a the object on which we study the effectivness of the forcefield. And if it was not just there but enter the beam at that moment at 90° angle...Than it can prove that this ray of particals can be used to block what ever enter it? If we can somehow find the right "mixture" of particals to accelerate.

Comment: is this what you have in mind: Free-Electron Laser https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser or traveling wave tube https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling-wave_tube

Comment: I will take a look at how these two technologies works and will get back if I have any questions afterwards. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sufficient array of laser beams, closely approximated together.
Hypothetically you can have a forcefield, not to "BLock" but certainly they wouldn't want to touch it, if it's hot enough to burn your flesh. Stopping a Bullet...........
A 50 caliber bullet (12.7x99mm) is lead and copper, When Fired it has a kinetic energy of 18 kilojoules, at a distance of 500 yards, about 6 kilojoules, and delivered over a surface area smaller than a US ten cent dime...A shield would need to melt or disentigrate over all mass 42-52 grams of lead and copper. Even if you melt the bullet, it's now a molten bullet. It has to be vaporized, which in turn now atomzied lead dust, not an ideal environment.